# Error: No build files found, please run `nuxt build` before launching `nuxt start

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, nuxt.js

I created a nuxt boilerplate using

> vue-cli nuxt-community/starter-template

I also created another using

> create-nuxt-app

. They both create my boilerplate properly. But anytime i try to build start my projects using

> yarn start

I get this error:

> Error: No build files found, please run `nuxt build` before launching
>   `nuxt start

furthermore, whenever i run

> nuxt build

I get this:

> No command 'nuxt' found, did you mean:  Command 'next' from package
>   'nmh' (universe) nuxt: command not found

but when i run

> yarn build

it builds and running yarn start a second time works but without hot module reloading. I don't know what the problem is. I don't know whether my yarn is broken or nuxt. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use nuxt commands (`nuxt build`)

add nuxt to global using `yarn global add nuxt`

check out your package.json for available commands in the scripts property

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
```

`nuxt build` or `yarn build` are commands for production build

Lastly,

use `nuxt` or `yarn dev` for development with hot module reloading

check out [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands) for more details

Comment: Thank your Charles

Comment: @TeddyMcZieuwa If the answer worked for you, you should mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 15):

`nuxt build` does not work from your command line, because you have not added it to your `PATH` variable. `npm run build` will look in your dependencies and use that instead.

To get a dev server running, use `npm run dev`. I believe by default it will start a dev server with live reload on port 3000. To build for production, use `npm run build` and `npm run start`.

Comment: thanks, i noticed that npm run dev, npm run build and npm run start work properly, but how do i fix this issue with yarn so that i can use yarn instead of npm. i want to run yarn start successfully.

Comment: @TeddyMcZieuwa yarn is a program built upon `npm`. If I remember correctly, you can use both `yarn run dev` or `yarn dev`, `yarn run build` or `yarn build` and `yarn run start` or `yarn start`. It executes scripts as defined in the package.json file.

Comment: I know, it works well with npm but whenever i use yarn, i get the errors stated above. I am confused.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it was a little problem with my linux. I ran sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt update. This fixed the issue. It had nothing to do with nuxt.